# How to use Deferred Lighting in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

A current Three.js application I am developing requires a lot of independent lights and so would benefit from a deferred lighting renderer.

Resources I have so far read on this suggest using **WebGLDeferredRenderer**, however when I define a renderer object as they suggest:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLDeferredRenderer({
width: window.innerWidth,
height: window.innerHeight,
scale: 1, antialias: true,
tonemapping: THREE.FilmicOperator, brightness: 2.5 });
```

and call the renderer as follows to draw the scene:

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

I get a blank screen, whereas if I use the standard WebGL renderer my scene is correctly rendered.

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
```

I can't seem to find a suitable example of implamenting deferred lighting in three.js.  Am I missing a library?  I only have **three.js** linked. perhaps this requires an additional library?

In my clone of three.js I can't find a copy of **WebGLDeferredRenderer.js**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebGLDeferredRenderer` has been removed. See [this post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7095) for more information, and follow the links to access the old code.

three.js r.73

Comment: Thank you, i wouldnt have found this information without your help.